# Sending Emails to Gmail: Disable Quoting of Repeated Content

Tags: email, gmail, html-email

Let's say you send out emails to your users, and those emails often have the same Subject and some of the content in the emails are the same. Well, Gmail likes to take the content that is the same in these scenarios and turn the text purple and collapse it where possible. Is there a way to tell (or trick) Gmail to NOT do this? Preferably without changing the subject (i.e. adding a unique id to the subject line).

Answer (score 0):

You may see this while testing multiple times, and the emails get accumulated one on top of the other (because it has the same subject). You would have to delete those emails and then test individually (one email at a time) to get the actual look of it.
Kinda tedious, but works :)